# Destructor not run after exiting console

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glew

I have been fiddling about with GLEW and win32 lately, and I've run into a problem. Whenever I exit my application by means of closing the window, the destructor of my Window class gets called and my openGL rendering context deleted. I can tell because I tested the program using CodeXL and it was positive that my context was deleted. But if I exit my application by killing my console (created by using AllocConsole()), my context does not get deleted according to CodeXL and leaks memory. Here's the destructor which is supposed to destroy my context:

```
Window::~Window()
{
    wglMakeCurrent(0,0);
    wglDeleteContext(renderingContext);
}
```

**Does anyone know why this destructor is *not* run when closing the console but *is* run whenever I kill the window?**

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Personally I think you should use a window manager like glut or GLFW. They will handle all that stuff because making an openGL app is hard enough without having to really worry about all that other stuff. GLFW is better because its better supported and more up to date.

Comment: @CarefulNow Yes, I know about such window managers (and have used SDL 2 for quite a while) but since I want to learn more about what is going on deep down, I decided to start at the bottom. My openGL/GLEW code is working just fine but I'm struggling with the win32 bit. I might as well just generalize this question to something like **Destructor of object not called upon closing console**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> my context does not get deleted according to CodeXL and leaks memory.

Yes. So what? The process has been killed so all resources it did consumed are freed by the operating system. In fact, if a process is going to terminate anyway, you *should not* clean up. Just save those things that need to be saved into persistent storage, do the necessary communication to get things in order with other processes and then just terminate.

Iterating over all resources in a process and freeing/deleting them is just as if you were cleaning up and giving a house a paint job right before the demolition crew tears it down with a wrecking ball.

***Memory leaks are never a problem at program termination!** Memory leaks are a problem during program runtime: They make a process consume ever more resources, which eventually leads to system resource exhaustion. The reaction of the operating system is to kill processes that hog system resources, to gain breathing space.*

> Does anyone know why this destructor is not run when closing the console but is run whenever I kill the window?

Because these two actions are very different things. When closing a window, the system sends a WM_CLOSE message, which you can react to by properly leaving the message loop, returning from the main function which signals the runtime to call the constructors of all the objects that go out of scope.

When you close the console window, your process looses its controlling terminal (AllocConsole attaches the console as controlling terminal). This is a critical condition and the default behaviour is immediate process termination.

#### Update

There are of course several legitimate things to do at process exit. Writing things to a log, maybe generate an autosave of the very last state of the program before exit, stuff like that. When it comes to Windows Console Windows you have to install a handler, that offers the operating system a way to gracefully deal with console events. The function for this is called a `HandlerRoutine`: (documented at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and set with [SetConsoleCtrlHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: "Memory leaks are never a problem at program termination!" Does this apply to graphic memory leaks too? And how could you "stop" this immediate termination and allow the program to properly exit and destroy the Window instance?

Comment: @thomw2o0o: Yes. All resources are freed. What do you think the graphics drivers are doing? Large parts of what graphics drivers do is giving the operating systems an interface to graphics resources. Everything happens through the OS and the OS will tell the graphics driver that a process died and the driver will then mark the memory formerly allocated as free-to-use.

Comment: @thomw2o0o: BTW: there may of course be several things that should be done at process termination. Maybe you want to write a savegame file. Or you want to let a multiplayer server know that the game was quit, instead of networking trouble.

Comment: @thomw2o0o: see my answer update on how to deal with console events.

Comment: @thomw2o0o: Yes, fair enough. But it's strongly advised not to go and try freeing each and every resource. Best case scenario you're wasting a couple of millions of CPU cycles. Worst case scenario: The operating system detected, that the resources you're about to free **and** the code that does the freeing have not been used for a while and decided to evict it from RAM (swap it out). Then your destruction code comes along, forcing the OS to do the havy duty job of lifting all of that back into RAM; just so that you could do a "white paint job" before the OS bulldozes it.

Comment: @thomw2o0o: If however a process dies without touching the things it no longer needs in a last effort, the OS doesn't even have to move it around and can simply discard it without second looks.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort you put into helping me solve this problem. I will bear your advice in mind and try to create a working HandlerRoutine (and accept this beautiful answer afterwards).